# Masking a variable in GrADS

Tags: plot, netcdf, grads

I am trying to plot a variable that is in a NetCDF file using [GrADS](http://iges.org/grads/) and I would like to plot only the values that are smaller than -20 (could be any other number as an example). I can't find a way to do it though. I saw several examples of variable substitution using both `maskout`and `const` (for example `define ones = const(const(maskout(p,p-10),1),0,-u)`, which is [here](http://www.iges.org/grads/gadoc/gradfuncmaskout.html)) but I couldn't make that work for my purposes.

I want the variable at a given point *not plotted* in case its value is below -20, and not this value change to another one in such point.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it using the command `maskout(p,p+20)`. The badly written documentation is what delayed me on this one. Answered here so that the community may benefit.
Thanks.