# How to plot specific value in GrADS

Tags: grads

I have found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28971401/masking-a-variable-in-grads) on plotting variable in GrADS and yes, the manual is poorly written. I want to plot values equal to zero only.

Say I have anomaly from -10 to 10 and I want to extract and plot the contour of absolute zero only, how can I do this in GrADS?

```
reinit
open somefile.ctl
set gxout 
d var #this plots the variable from -10 to 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to plot the '0' contour line, just use the 'set clevs 0'
So in your code, it should be:

```
reinit
open somefile.ctl

set gxout contour
set clevs 0

d var #this plots the variable from -10 to 10
```

If you want to "extract" the contour line, the best way to do this is to save it as a line shapefile.Like this:

```
set gxout shp
set shp -ln -fmt 8 4 linem
set shpattr AUTHOR string test
set shpattr TYPE string grid contours
set shpattr DESC string anomaly
d var
```

See this link for more details [Link](http://cola.gmu.edu/grads/gadoc/gradcomdsetshp.html)
Then to plot the shapefile,just use 'draw shp (name of shapefile)'